# How to define the sum of multiple columns values into one column in Django models.py

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I have a django models.py as follows:

```
from django.db import models 


class StudentList(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Marks_of_each_Student(models.Model):
    student_name=models.ForeignKey(StudentList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    s1=models.IntegerField()
    s2=models.IntegerField()
    s3=models.IntegerField()
    Total=models.IntegerField(default=0,editable=False)
    
    def calculate_total(self):
        return self.s1+self.s2+self.s3

    def save(self):
        self.Total=self.calculate_total()
```

I want to have a column names `Total` containing the value of s1+s2+s3 in it when entered via ORM commands through shell. I tried the following but it did not worked out.

```
from main_page.models import StudentList,Marks_of_each_Student
>>> x=StudentList(name="XYZ NAME")
>>> x.save()
>>> x1=Marks_of_each_Student(student_name=x,s1=90,s2=90,s3=90)
>>> x1.save()
>>> x1
<Marks_of_each_Student: Marks_of_each_Student object (1)>
>>> x1.Total
0
```

All other columns are having the correct values but this `Total` is not giving correct results.

How do I proceed to make sure that the changes are reflected in `Total` column and also I was not getting these data saved for `Marks_of_each_Student` in MySQL table.

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the parent save() function is called after you update self.Total:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Total=self.calculate_total()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from main_page.models import StudentList, Marks_of_each_Student

#If you want to create a new object and save it to studentlist
>>> b = StudentList(name='Beatles Blog')
>>> b.save()

# Retrieve a object by name so you can save it to marks of each student
>>> instance = StudentList.objects.get(name="Beatles Blog")
>>> instance
>>> Beatles Blog

# Create a new object to marks of each student:
>>> obj = Marks_of_each_Student(student_name=instance, s1=90, s2=90, s3=90)
# calculate the total
>>> obj.Total = obj.s1 + obj.s2 + obj.s3
# Save the object
>>> obj.save()

>>>obj.Total
>>>270
```

**remove:**

```
def calculate_total(self):
        return self.s1+self.s2+self.s3

def save(self):
    self.Total=self.calculate_total()
```